# Android app crashes on button click, when loading another window

Tags: java, android, parsing

I am writing an app and using Parse to store the data. All is running good until I click 1 button which opens another window (form), it will open the first time, but going back and clicking it again causes the app to crash.. the error given says;
"
`Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context, String, String)`
"
Here is my code;

```
public class NewListPage extends Activity {

private EditText Name;
private Button Add;
private ListView lv;

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "MWxapoogl7x9203UNFGES0BH5QYh8qKAfijws3qk", "oLpiKtzx9N2th2o6YhfaAo8ZkmtiIevpM1jtzDzD");


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newlistpage);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your logcat? post it

Comment: There isnt enough information in your question. Please add some more. Add logs , show the code where you are making a transition to the other activity.

Comment: Your error clearly says that you need to write this line `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` after your `Parse` `initialize`. Its too simple.

Comment: Put  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newlistpage); lines above your parse lines and try

Comment: create Application class of your own and right Parse initialisation code inside that.

Comment: This is the code for the transition to the other activity; `Button New = (Button) findViewById(R.id.New);
        New.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(LaunchPage.this, NewListPage.class);
                LaunchPage.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });`

Answer (score -1):

Mate, you should move the the following line code:

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

above the Parse code below:

`Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, "MWxapoogl7x9203UNFGES0BH5QYh8qKAfijws3qk", "oLpiKtzx9N2th2o6YhfaAo8ZkmtiIevpM1jtzDzD");`